# background process with "&" and problem with buffering

Tags: shell-script, background-process, buffer

I've written this script in the ~/.bashrc file and I've sourced the file, but it's not working properly. It's purpose is to open the link provided by the jupyter notebook in the Chrome browser in a new tab.

```
chrome(){
        echo $1 # <--- shows that jupfire is sending an empty string
        # I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux
        "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" $1
}

jupfire(){
        jupyter notebook 2>juptemp &
        sleep 3
        chrome "$(tail -1 juptemp | grep http)"
        rm juptemp
}
```

After searching and trying some unsuccessful ways, I've come to the conclusion that it has something to do with I/O buffering. Probably the "&" after the first line of "jupfire" function causes the stderr to not be flushed into juptemp, and thus an empty string is sent to the chrome function.

It seems that I should use "stdbuf" but I have no idea how, by checking the manual page, I came up with this: `stdbuf -e0 jupyter notebook 2>juptemp &` as the first line of the jupfire function, but it's still not working.(to be clear, by "not working" I mean it's opening a new tab in chrome browser with its address bar being empty). If the problem is with buffering, could you guide me use the flushing in the proper way? thanks.

Edit: This is a sample output of the command "jupyter notebook":

> ```
> ...
> To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
>     file:///home/mojtabaa/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-28353-open.html
> Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
>     http://localhost:8888/?token=2ead351a97edd97dc5b5fd0aa80b6872af9f9e5c6b9ef10b
> ```

Comment: What is the contents of `juptemp`?  What output does `jupyter notebook` provide?  Your `chrome` function is being executed immediately after `jupyter notebook` starts which may not be enough time for it to start writing output to `juptemp`

Comment: @Jesse_b I've edited the question to consider these.

Comment: What is the point of `grep http` you are only going to get one line from `tail` anyway.  Are you positive the line you need is always the last line?  I.E. no trailing newline with whitespace?

Comment: @Jesse_b that's right, I only used grep because initially I suspected that the whitespace behind the url might be the source of my issue... but it's not necessary as you say. That being said, I just deleted the grep part too and it still makes no difference.

Comment: What is the output of `tail -1 juptemp`?  Specifically what is the output of it immediately after `sleep 3`?

Comment: @Jesse_b it's whitespace. but if I comment the "rm" command and check the "juptemp" file after running "jupfire", it does contain the url.

Comment: So you don't want to `tail -1`...you need another way of finding the url in your file.  You could just skip the tail altogether and simply grep for `http` but that snippet you provided indicates their may be multiple URLs which could cause a problem, and without knowing more about the file I can't say there wont be `http` in it elsewhere as well.  I recommend just doing a `cat juptemp` immediately after sleep 3 and see how much information is in it at that point.

Comment: @Jesse_b yes, the url is repeated multiple times(two times indeed) in the output of the "jupyter notebook" command. But what's wrong with tail? Do you think "tail" is the reason behind this issue?

Comment: It is because you are only getting the last line and the last line **does not** contain the URL

Comment: @Jesse_b I used cat on juptemp as you said and it contains nothing(it's empty at that point).

Comment: So you probably have to wait for the command to run longer before the file contains any output.  Have you run the command normally and observed how long it takes to output?

Comment: @Jesse_b Oh thanks! Yes this was the problem :(. Thanks for your help. It's working fine now.

Comment: Can @Jesse_b post his answer and then aderchox accept it?